# Ruby Convert Date

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a page that is returning this as a date new Date(1357106400000) (which I believe is Javascript).

How do I convert that using Ruby.  I've tried:

Date.new(1357106400000)
DateTime.new(1357106400000)
and many others, but I can't get the correct date to display.

The date returned should be 12/09/2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've got the time in milliseconds since the epoch, and the function you're looking for is [Time#at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-at).  But you need to down-convert into seconds before calling.  For example:

```
[holt@Michaela ~]$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Time.at(1357106400000)
=> Wed Dec 28 00:00:00 +0000 44974
irb(main):002:0> Time.at(1357106400000 / 1000)
=> Wed Jan 02 06:00:00 +0000 2013
irb(main):003:0>
```

Not the exact day you thought it was, but probably still correct.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript:

```
> new Date(1357106400000)
Wed Jan 02 2013 06:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

In Ruby:

```
>  require 'date'
> DateTime.strptime("1357106400000", "%Q")
=> #<DateTime: 2013-01-02T06:00:00+00:00 ((2456295j,21600s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. I originally put the wrong value. I should have put 1355119200000. which gives me 12/10/2012 with your answer. However, on the site the date is 12/09/2012. I checked a few others and they are all 1 day after the date posted